# Bernoulli distribution estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

For a Bernoulli distribution X1, ..., Xn ∼ with p = 0.5. Lets define Yn as max(X1...Xn). Assume this to be a problem of coin tossing and hence find the following:

1. Estimate of Y[n].
2. Plot the estimate of Y[n] against n for finite points.
3. Differentiate Yn from Xi?

For a Bernoulli distribution with p as 0.5, won't Yn be 0.5?
Also won't E[Yn] be just Sigma(x*p(x)) which is 0.5? I have no clue on how to plot a graph for the same or the distribution. Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: One implicit assumption in here is that $n$ is a positive integer; otherwise, the enumeration $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

To help you understand the question, let's consider an example.

Suppose you have a fair coin, and you decide to toss it $n = 5$ times.  For each $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, if the outcome of the coin is heads, $X_i = 1$; otherwise, $X_i = 0$.  In other words, on the $i^{\rm th}$ trial, you count the number of heads you obtained ($1$ if you got heads, $0$ if you got tails).

Next, for the set of all five coin tosses, you say that $Y = 1$ if you observed *at least one head*; otherwise, if the outcome of all five tosses were tails, you say $Y = 0$.

Let's say that you performed this experiment and you got $(H, T, T, H, T)$, or written in terms of the $X_i$, $$(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5) = (1, 0, 0, 1, 0).$$  Then $$Y_5 = \max(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5) = \max(1, 0, 0, 1, 0) = 1.$$

In this case, what is $\Pr[Y_5 = 0]$?  What is $\Pr[Y_5 = 1]$?  Now, can you compute the expectation $$\operatorname{E}[Y_5] = 0 \cdot \Pr[Y_5 = 0] + 1 \cdot \Pr[Y_5 = 1] = \,?$$

Next, how can you generalize your reasoning to consider the probability distribution of the case where the coin is flipped $n$ times?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. When n is undefined (not a constant number), how do I represent E[Yn] am I expected to just provide the expression like the one you stated above? Also, the second part says that we need to plot E[Yn] for every value of n. In that case, for E[Yn]  be an expression again? How do you convert an expression into a value? Do I assume the outcomes of X1...Xn and draw a corresponding graph?

Comment: @AbhiramNatarajan  Did you actually perform the calculations I outlined in my answer?  What did you get?  Did you perform the calculation for a different choice of $n$?  If I asked you, what is the probability of getting zero heads in $n$ tosses of a fair coin, would you insist that the answer be a number, or would you perform the computation and state that **the result is a function of** $n$?

Comment: yes I performed the calculations that you did. For different values of n the value of Yn may change based on if there it atleast one 1 in X1...Xn. So for large distributions, Yn should always be 1. If you asked about the probability of getting 0 heads in n tosses, I agree the answer should be a function of n but I have no idea on how to represent it.